# How can one set up audio on Arch Linux supporting multiple programs emitting audio at once without creating an asoundrc?

Tags: arch-linux, audio

I'd like to set up audio on my Arch Linux system so that multiple programs can access my sound card and emit audio at a time.

Unfortunately, the asoundrc file confuses me in its syntax, presently I have this file:

```
cm.!spdif {
     type hw
     card 1
     device 0
}

pcm.!default {
     type plug
     slave {
           pcm "plug:dmix" # this is a line is based on https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=95582
           # I have also tried pcm "dmix", based on the thread. It failed to get multiple sound processes running simultaneously. 
     }
}
```

and while one program at a time can emit sound, whenever I try to run audio in another program none is emitted, like running:

```
speaker-test -c 2
```

emits no sound when another program is accessing my sound card. It's irritating as I frequently pause audio-emitting programs and start others and my present situation won't let me.

Here is the output of `lspci | grep -i audio`:

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
```

So my question is, "How can I set this up in a nice, simple and automated way? Is there a program I can install that will set up the audio without a problem?"

Comment: You have to get a soundcard which supports hardware mixing of multiple channels. Or use any software mixing daemon, like esd or pulseaudio.

Comment: My sound card has supported multiple programs trying to use it on other distros and in the past on this Arch system so I know it can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nice, simple, and automated way: Just make sure all programs use `plughw` instead of `hw` when they specify the audio device they want. That will put an automatically generated `dmix` in front of the real `hw` device.

To make this the default, your `.asoundrc` file should look like:

```
pcm.!default "plughw:2,0"
ctl.!default "plughw:2,0"
```

with the correct numbers identifying the soundcard you want (see e.g. `aplay -l`).

**Edit**

Yes, the numers are *card* and *device* in that order. You can add a third *subdevice* number if there's more than one subdevice (`plughw:2,0,1`).

Comment: What do 2 and 0 correspond to in aplay -l output? Card number, device number in that order per chance?

Comment: Aha it seems like I was right as to the order as it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: One problem, is how do I just the volume now? I'm using i3 the only way I can adjust it is using alsamixer which won't work now, it gives `ALSA lib control.c:1262:(snd_ctl_open_conf) Invalid type for CTL default definition
cannot open mixer: Invalid argument`

Comment: It seems like this doesn't allow multiple programs to access the sound card, it just means that after a program has been paused or closed it's easier for the next program to access the sound card. At the moment I have RS's NXT Client, SuperTuxKart, both muted and whenever I open VLC I get an audio error I got before I tried this solution -- https://imgur.com/nLH6ah7.png. When these games aren't running VLC runs fine, without this error. This solution lead to me asking this question on the Gentoo forum -- https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8149962.html#8149962.

Comment: Actually it does work, but only on Arch, on Gentoo with the same packages it doesn't. Oh well, answer still deserves the acceptance.